# kafka consumer batch listener polling records based on sized of the messager

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want to consumer to consume messages in  batch based on the length/size of the message batch means batch of 1kb and max poll.record with 100. at max it polls 100 message or 1kb of message.

```
max.poll.records =100
```

How do I set 1kb of message at max in the batch ?
I have tried with `max.partition.fetch.bytes=1024` but I am getting 100 message even message batch  is larger than 1024 bytes. How to control this behaviour ?

How do I set at max 1kb of message with cap of 100 message per batch at max ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config in consumer, such as `max.partition.fetch.bytes` or `fetch.max.bytes` both are **not a absolute maximum**.

> Records are fetched in batches by the consumer, and if the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this value, the record batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress

kafka recommend to define via `message.max.bytes` (broker config) or `max.message.bytes` (topic config).

You can find all detail about kafka config here: [max.partition.fetch.bytes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.partition.fetch.bytes)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is each poll can have multiple fetch request right.... We fetch. Max. Bytes controlls only fetch request but not max records to be polled based on the bytes

Comment: Yes. `records` for `poll`, `bytes` for `underlying fetching behavior`